# Extend TypeScript module

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings

I'm using a library called `@xstyled/styled-components`. It provides a wrapper around `styled-components`. The issue I'm having is, it doesn't have types.

So I've created a `index.d.ts` file that looks like this:

```
declare module '@xstyled/styled-components' {
  import styled from 'styled-components';
  export = styled;
}
```

This issue is, this only gives me types for the `styled` function.

Is there a way for me to export all the types from `styled-components`?

I tried below, but no luck either.

```
declare module '@xstyled/styled-components' {
  import * as styled from 'styled-components';
  export = styled;
}
```

Thank you :)